# Logged in to SO chat using Google account, but logged out when entering a room

Tags: bug, chat, authentication

I can authenticate successfully with a Google account at chat.stackoverflow.com, but when I navigate to a room I'm not logged in any more.

Is anyone else having this issue? Or is it just me?

I can authenticate with the same account at Stack Overflow with no problem.

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts signed in with Google? When I do this certain aspects of the site do not allow this and request me to log in and sometimes even that doesn't work.

Comment: Ok this is still not working. I have signed out all Google accounts, I have cleared browsing data including all cookies. Still no joy.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure, maybe try a different web browser?

Comment: Tried that too, have tried two different PC's in two diferent networks as well exact same result. I think my account is definitely foobar in some subtle way.